# Flutter Multiple Heroes That Share The Same Tag Within A Subtree

Tags: android, ios, flutter, animation, dart

I am trying to have a hero animation from  a post view screen to a full screen post view. As far as I can see, it seems quite normal(my code) and I don't really understand why I am getting this error...

I don't have any other Hero widgets in my code, so I cannot see why I should be getting this error...

Here is the error I am getting:

```
There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.
```

Here is my code:

```
Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Hero(
                tag: 'test',
                child: Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.grey.shade400.withOpacity(0.5),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                        ),
                        width: 120,
                        height: 40,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          itemCount: 3,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return _configureEmoji(index);
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(widget.post.imageURL),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Here is where I want the hero animation to go to:

```
class FullScreenView extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imageURL;
  FullScreenView({this.imageURL});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Hero(
        tag: 'test',
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(imageURL),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot and I really appreciate your help!

Comment: How are you `Navigating` to `FullScreenView `?  I think there might be some issue in`Navigation` code between `PageRoute`s . `Hero` animations are for animating a particular widget between 2 `pages`. [Reference](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Hero-class.html) and 
 [Example in docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/hero-animations)

Comment: I am not using any heroTag in my entire app but still getting error at the compile time "There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree" kindly suggest what is the issue and how can I solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## Plausible reason

The Hero widget doesn't know which Hero you clicked on, so it uses the next screen's Hero tag as a reference to perform a screen search that will close by looking for the Hero with that same tag. If there is more than one Hero with the same tag then an error will be returned as it is not known which Hero should do the animation.

[image]

## Solution

The solution I use is to identify each Hero using as a reference the content inside it and in the navigation I insert this id (tag) in the navigation push argument and then add this id in the Hero of the target screen.

The most plausible way for your project is to use the post id as the Hero tag, that when sending the post data to the next screen already use the post id on the screen's Hero.

[image]

Comment: Would you mind adding some code, that matches your explanation?